# different HTML-structure with other languages

Tags: theming

When I add a new basic page in default language, the HTMLstructure is like:

```
<div class="block block-system block-main block-system-main odd block-without-title" id="block-system-main">    <div class="block-inner clearfix">
    <div class="content clearfix">
    <article ...>
```

But when I translate that page (or create a new page in another language), the article is not within the div's. The HTML-structure is like:

```
<article ...>
```

I've no idea how to solve this. Where do I have to look? Is this a setting, or do I have to change s